# Fetch youtube private playlist using api v3 android

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I want to fetch my private playlist in my android app and show it to user.

First I would like to know if its possible to display my private playlist to other users via my android app.
If yes, then can you please help me out with some code ? It will be of great help.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's private, only when you login via OAuth2 you can fetch it, when other people logins to your app, they won't be able to.

But you can make your playlist "unlisted" and save it's id. As long as your app knows the playlist id, other people can fetch it as well.

Comment: HI it would be awesome if you could ans this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792340/post-comments-to-youtube-videos-using-youtube-api-v3-android