# Post comments to youtube videos using youtube api v3 Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can I add comments on a particular youtube video via my app? Using youtube api v3.
I am able to get the comments of a youtube video using this url:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+VIDEO_ID+"/comments?prettyprint=true

How can I post comments?

Comment: Referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148761/is-there-a-way-to-add-comments-through-youtube-api-v3 and some other sources it is not possible to comment through API V3. I am also looking for a solution on that.

Answer (score 2):

```
You can use you tube "CommentThreads: insert" to post your comment via app

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert
```

following is the api call

```
Post url : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And body for the API call is:

```
Body

    { "snippet":{
      "topLevelComment":{
       "snippet":{
        "textOriginal": "YOUR_COMMENT_HERE",
        "videoId": "VIDEO_ID"
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

Also add don't forget to add following scope
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl

Comment: The api call is returning 401 Unauthorized when I try to insert the comment. I know the api key is not the problem because when I use another api call like search the api key is the right one and returns the response. I know that is due to the scope, but I don't understand how can I send the scope via fiddler or via my c# console app. I'm able to insert a comment using the google api explorer api, but it's not my target. Anyone knows how to set up the scope described above?

Comment: @user354427 You need to use an access token, not an API key to make art POST request (as you need to be logged in with a YouTube account).

Comment: [Rohan Goyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7378327) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66559281) saying to use this instead `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&videoId={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`. I do not know if they are correct or not. Let me know if I should delete this comment.