# Post comments to youtube videos using youtube api v3 via Fiddler or custom console app

Tags: youtube-api, console-application, fiddler

The question is about inserting comments using the version 3 of the youtube api and via a crude http request (with fiddler or custom console app).

I'm able to retrieve videos sending a request to the search method with my api key, but inserting a comment is different. The response I get is 401 Unauthorized but I'm sending the correct api key.

I think this is due to the scope:
Also add don't forget to add following scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
as it is said in [Post comments to youtube videos using youtube api v3 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792340/post-comments-to-youtube-videos-using-youtube-api-v3-android) but I don't know how to set it up in my app or via fiddler (yes with api explorer provided by google, but they have a popup implemented to select this scope).

Anybody knows how can I add the scope and set it to youtube.force-ssl?

Thanks

Comment: were you able to sort this?

Comment: No, I wasn't. It was a toy project and I left it next day. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Even I am looking for a solution :(  I do not understand the document :(